# How to use modelMapper to convert nested classes

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a simple class that I want to map to a DTO class using modelMapper.

```
class Source {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    List<Thing> things;

    // getters and setters follows
    }

    class Thing {

    private String thingCode;
    private String thingDescription;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and I want to convert these to a sourceDTO that contains a list of ThingDTOs, for example

```
class sourceDTO {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    List<ThingDTO> things;

    // getters and setters.
    }

     class ThingDTO {

    private String thingCode;
    private String thingDescription;

    // getters and setters
}
```

If I drop my list of Things and list of ThingsDTO then modelmapper is a delight to use,

```
 modelMapper.map(source, SourceDTO.class);
```

But I can't work out how to get the mapper to convert the List of Things to List of ThingDTOs. From the documentation, I think I need to create a mapper class that extends PropertyMap but I can't work out how to configure it.

Any pointers to the relevant documentation would be welcome

Comment: Found this useful. Thank you for posting this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think if you configure your ModelMapper as LOOSE or STANDARD it will do for you.

```
modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
```

Otherwhise you could try next:

1. You may create a converter like:

   ```
   public class ListThingToThingDTOConverter implements Converter<List<Thing>, List<ThingDTO>> {


   @Override
   public List<ThingDTO> convert(MappingContext<List<Thing>, List<ThingDTO>> context) {
       List<Thing> source = context.getSource();
       List<ThingDTO> output = new ArrayList<>();
       ...
       //Convert programmatically List<Thing> to List<ThingDTO>
       ...

       return output;
     }}
   ```
2. Then customize a Mapping Thing to ThingDTO as next:

   ```
       public class SourceToSourceDTOMap extends PropertyMap<Thing, ThingDTO> {
             @Override
             protected void configure(){
                  using(new ListThingToThingDTOConverter()).map(source.getThings()).setThings(null);
             }
   ```
3. Finally you must add SourceToSourceDTOMap to your ModelMapper as below:

   ```
   modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
   modelMapper.addMappings(new SourceToSourceDTOMap());
   ```

Comment: I have a slightly different use-case. Would you mind taking a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69215180/9768291

Comment: Thank you for this. I dont know why this is not very well explain in many places.. This is like the basic requirement and had to search around a lot to find the solution for this. Appreciate your answer. Save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can map like the below code by creating generics . link for reference

http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/generics/

imports :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.TypeToken;
```

In your service or controller class:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
Type listType = new TypeToken<SourceDTO>(){}.getType();
SourceDTO sourceDTO = modelMapper.map(source,listType);
```