# ModelMapper: transferring attribute from root to each elements of a list

Tags: java, mapping, modelmapper

## Model

We use `org.modelmapper` for our bean mapping. Here is the data model (using `public` for brevity):

```java
class Root {
  public String foo;
  public List<Element> elements;
}
class Element {
  public String foo; // <- this is the field that should be replicated from RootDTO
  public String bar;
}


class RootDTO {
  public String foo;
  public List<ElementDTO> elements;
}
class ElementDTO {
  public String bar; // notice how there is no `foo` attribute in the DTO
}
```

## Expected mapping (example)

Input:

```java
RootDTO
|-- foo = "foo"
|-- elements
    |--ElementDTO(bar="bar")
    |--ElementDTO(bar="something")
    |--ElementDTO(bar="else")
```

Output:

```java
Root
|-- foo = "foo"
|-- elements
    |--Element(foo="foo", bar="bar")
    |--Element(foo="foo", bar="something")
    |--Element(foo="foo", bar="else")
```

## Problem

As you can see, `ModelMapper` would handle this case very easily if it wasn't for the `Element.foo` field that should take its value from `RootDTO.foo`.

How do I configure `ModelMapper` to achieve my goal?

I'd want the solution to:

1. Not require developers to change the mapping's code if new matching attributes were to be introduced in the model.
2. To be done through a single method call to the `ModelMapper`.

### Current configuration

```java
myModelMapper.typeMap(ElementDTO.class, Element.class).implicitMappings();
myModelMapper.typeMap(RootDTO.class, Root.class).implicitMappings();
```

### Results when using that configuration

```java
Root mappedRoot = myModelMapper.map(rootDto, Root.class);

assertEquals(rootDto.foo, mappedRoot.foo);
assertEquals(rootDto.elements.size(), mappedRoot.elements.size());
// let's assume we have 1 Element
assertEquals(rootDto.elements.get(0).bar, mappedRoot.elements.get(0).bar);

assertEquals(rootDto.foo, mappedRoot.elements.get(0).foo); // FAILS! But this is what I want
// indeed, the value of `mappedRoot.elements.get(0).foo` is `null` because it was not mapped
```

## Explored avenues

### Idea 1

It seems to me like if I could set an **order** I could simply configure it this way:

```java
Converter<RootDTO, Root> replicateFooValue = new Converter<>() {
  @Override
  public Root convert(MappingContext<RootDTO, Root> context) {
    final String valueToReplicate = context.getSource().foo;
    for (Element elem : context.getDestination().elements) {
      elem.foo = valueToReplicate;
    }
    return context.getDestination();
  }
};

myModelMapper.typeMap(ElementDTO.class, Element.class).implicitMappings();
myModelMapper.typeMap(RootDTO.class, Root.class).implicitMappings()
    .thenUseConverter(replicateFooValue);
```

... but I do not think this is possible.

### Idea 2

If I could use the `ModelMapper`'s mapping functionality from within the `Converter<>` itself, then I could use the `implicitMappings()` before trying to simply set the value I want, but once again: I do not think that this is possible.

### Idea 3

One way to be sure that it'd work would be:

```java
Converter<RootDTO, Root> myCustomConverter = new Converter<>() {
  @Override
  public Root convert(MappingContext<RootDTO, Root> context) {
    final Root mappedRoot = new Root();
    // map each field individually, by hand
    return mappedRoot;
  }
};

myModelMapper.addConverter(myCustomConverter);
```

... but it requires maintenance if I was to add new fields in my data model.

### Idea 4

Add a `Converter<RootDTO, Element>` that would only populate the `foo` value. That would result in the following usage:

```java
Root mappedRoot = myModelMapper.map(rootDto, Root.class);
mappedRoot.elements.forEach(e -> myModelMapper.map(rootDto, e));
```

This is not ideal because then the entire expected behavior is not encapsulated in a single call: the developers have to know (and remember) to make that second call as well to achieve the desired mapping.

### Idea 5

Make a utility class that encompasses the logic shown by `Idea 4`.

This is also a bad idea because it requires developers to know (and remember) about why they need to do that specific mapping this way instead of using the `ModelMapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there *is* a way to introduce some ordering. Here is the solution:

```java
Converter<RootDTO, Root> finishMapping = new Converter<>() {
  @Override
  public Root convert(MappingContext<RootDTO, Root> context) {
    final String srcFoo = context.getSource();
    var dest = context.getDestination();

    dest.elements.stream().forEach(e -> e.foo = srcFoo);
    return dest;
  }
};

myModelMapper.typeMap(ElementDTO.class, Element.class).implicitMappings();
myModelMapper.typeMap(RootDTO.class, Root.class).implicitMappings()
    .setPostConverter(finishMapping); // this is executed AFTER the implicit mapping
```

Comment: Thanks! I've this same problem and your answer is perfect!