# ModelMapper reverse map from a destination field onto itself

Tags: java, modelmapper

Is there a way `ModelMapper` can reverse map a value already set using `PropertyMap` again to another field in `destination`? In other words, I have a computed value and the same has to be set on two fields using `PropertyMap`, computation changes the value everytime and cannot be invoked twice `using(converter)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- ModelMapper: `3.1.0`.

It seems that by the «ModelMapper» library design:

- There is no way to «reuse» the converted source value to set multiple destination property values.

## Possible solution

A post-converter may be used to copy a value from one destination property to another.

### Draft example program

#### `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### `Customer` class

```java
class Customer {
    private String fullName;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(final String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

#### `CustomerDTO` class

```java
import java.util.StringJoiner;

class CustomerDTO {
    private String fullName;
    private String copyOfFullName;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(final String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getCopyOfFullName() {
        return copyOfFullName;
    }

    public void setCopyOfFullName(final String copyOfFullName) {
        this.copyOfFullName = copyOfFullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", CustomerDTO.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
            .add("fullName='" + fullName + "'")
            .add("copyOfFullName='" + copyOfFullName + "'")
            .toString();
    }
}
```

#### `Program` class

```java
import org.modelmapper.Converter;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

public final class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFullName("Full name");

        final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        final Converter<Customer, CustomerDTO> customerConverter = context -> {
            final CustomerDTO destination = context.getDestination();
            // NOTE: Copying the value of the full name property to another property.
            destination.setCopyOfFullName(destination.getFullName());
            return destination;
        };
        modelMapper.typeMap(
            Customer.class, CustomerDTO.class
        ).addMapping(
            Customer::getFullName, CustomerDTO::setFullName
        ).setPostConverter(customerConverter);

        modelMapper.validate();

        final CustomerDTO customerDTO = modelMapper.map(customer, CustomerDTO.class);
        System.out.println(customerDTO);
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
CustomerDTO[fullName='Full name', copyOfFullName='Full name']
```

## Additional references

- Post-converter example. [java - ModelMapper: transferring attribute from root to each elements of a list - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215180/modelmapper-transferring-attribute-from-root-to-each-elements-of-a-list).

  - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271579).

Comment: Thanks, this should help. I use `extends PropertyMap<A, B>`, is there a way postConverter can be added there in the mapping defined in `PropertyMap`?

Comment: Dear @Rayyan, Could you please update the question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to provide a better understanding?